# Mutate (apply an operation on) several differently sized subsets of columns (containing patterns in a vector) with automatic naming in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame as follows:

```
df = data.frame(a1 = c(1:6, rep(NA,6)),
                a2 = c(rep(NA,6), 7:12),
                b1 = rep(c(1,NA), 6),
                b2 = rep(c(NA,2), 6),
                c1 = rep(c(1,NA,NA), each=4),
                c2 = rep(c(NA,2,NA), each=4),
                c3 = rep(c(NA,NA,3), each=4))
#    a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2 c3
# 1   1 NA  1 NA  1 NA NA
# 2   2 NA NA  2  1 NA NA
# 3   3 NA  1 NA  1 NA NA
# 4   4 NA NA  2  1 NA NA
# 5   5 NA  1 NA NA  2 NA
# 6   6 NA NA  2 NA  2 NA
# 7  NA  7  1 NA NA  2 NA
# 8  NA  8 NA  2 NA  2 NA
# 9  NA  9  1 NA NA NA  3
# 10 NA 10 NA  2 NA NA  3
# 11 NA 11  1 NA NA NA  3
# 12 NA 12 NA  2 NA NA  3
```

Here, there are 3 groups of columns, each containing a pattern in the name (2 cols with `a`, 2 cols with `b` and 3 cols with `c`), and I need to apply an operation on these subsets to summarise each of them in a single column (named after the common pattern) - here, simply by merging them to remove the NA's.

I could do it with base R for example as follows:

```
sapply(c('a', 'b', 'c'), function(x) rowSums(df[,grepl(x, names(df))], na.rm=T))
#       a b c
# [1,]  1 1 1
# [2,]  2 2 1
# [3,]  3 1 1
# [4,]  4 2 1
# [5,]  5 1 2
# [6,]  6 2 2
# [7,]  7 1 2
# [8,]  8 2 2
# [9,]  9 1 3
# [10,] 10 2 3
# [11,] 11 1 3
# [12,] 12 2 3
```

But I can't figure out how to do it in `dplyr`?
I suppose through some smart combination of `mutate_each_` and `select(contains())` etc but I can't get it...??

As there are potentially many subsets of columns, I need a totally automatic solution where I just give the pattern vector (here, `c('a','b','c')`) (i.e., I don't want to manually name the output columns).

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `map` from `tidyverse` package (`purrr`) after `split`ting the dataset by the column names without the numbers (`sub(...)`)

```
library(tidyverse)
split.default(df, sub("\\d+", "", names(df))) %>% 
                      map_df(~rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))
#     A tibble: 12 × 3
#       a     b     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      1     1     1
#2      2     2     1
#3      3     1     1
#4      4     2     1
#5      5     1     2
#6      6     2     2
#7      7     1     2
#8      8     2     2
#9      9     1     3
#10    10     2     3
#11    11     1     3
#12    12     2     3
```

Comment: So everything is done with base R while `sapply` was replaced with `purrr::map_df` (and a `%>%`) so it will look cooler? I don't understand what's going on SO anymore.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  The `split` and `rowSums` are from `base R`.  There is no question about that. But, here, we are using a method to connect with chains.

Answer (score 2):

A general tidyverse solution might require you to reshape first. Unfortunately, we have to keep track of the rows during this operation, which lenghtens the code quite a bit.

```
patterns <- c('a', 'b', 'c')

df %>% 
  mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -i) %>% 
  mutate(group = do.call(coalesce, purrr::map(patterns, ~stringr::str_match(tmp$key, .)))) %>% 
  group_by(group, i) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  spread(group, value) %>% 
  select(-i)
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 × 3
>        a     b     c
> *  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1      1     1     1
> 2      2     2     1
> 3      3     1     1
> 4      4     2     1
> 5      5     1     2
> 6      6     2     2
> 7      7     1     2
> 8      8     2     2
> 9      9     1     3
> 10    10     2     3
> 11    11     1     3
> 12    12     2     3
> ```

You could perform any arbitrary operation on the original rows by changing the epxression in the `summarise` statement. It also generalizes to any arbitrary pattern.

You could potentially use the SE paradigm to directly code an appropriate `transmute` function, but I can't figure out exactly how (with the upcoming `dplyr` `0.6.0`). A start for a single pattern:

```
patterns <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
cols <- map(patterns, ~map(grep(., names(df), value = TRUE), rlang::as_symbol))

transmute(df, !!patterns[1] := coalesce(!!!cols[[1]]))
```

Gives:

> ```
>     a
> 1   1
> 2   2
> 3   3
> 4   4
> 5   5
> 6   6
> 7   7
> 8   8
> 9   9
> 10 10
> 11 11
> 12 12
> ```